# Laravel validate int or float numbers as string

Tags: php, laravel

in my project. all mount maybe int or float or was even double.in database amount column type is `varchar` and for each choose amount by user i have simple limitation, for example amount must be more than some value and less that some value. but i get error validation in laravel.

```
$ps = DB::table('merchant_web_service')->whereCustomerKey($request->input('customer_key'))->first();

/* $ps->minimum_range_buy is 5 and $ps->maximum_range_buy is 10*/

$validate_amount      = Validator::make($request->all(), 
            ['amount' => "required|min:$ps->minimum_range_buy|max:$ps->maximum_range_buy"]);
```

validator error is:

```
"The amount must be at least 10 characters."
```

my test amount values: `1000,100.1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you didn't specify any rule for the input data type, it validates it as a string. Try `numeric` and `between` rules.

```
$validate_amount = Validator::make($request->all(), 
     ['amount'=>
      "required|numeric|between:$ps->minimum_range_buy,$ps->maximum_range_buy"
     ]);
```

Comment: this values `1000`, `10000.0` and `10000.00` supported by numeric ?

Comment: Yes `numeric` is like a `decimal` data type.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$rules = [
'your_field' => 'required|regex:/^\d*(\.\d{2})?$/'
]
```

Comment: for `100.1` i get this message: `The amount format is invalid`

Comment: are you tried [numeric](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-numeric) validation rule?

Comment: amout is not exactly int or float, is support amout values such as `1000` ,`1000.1`, `1000.02` ?